# Xamarin Google Maps StreetView - no option to force outdoor location

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have found missing functionality in Google Maps v2(Android.Gms.Maps) on Xamarin.Android and in Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps on Xamarin.iOS.
The problem is related to creating a StreetView. According to documentation(native Android SDK) there are 4 methods how you can set streetview's location using SetPosition method. Two of them accept parameter StreetViewSource by which you can force the StreetView to use only outdoor images. Here is the snippet from documentation:

```
private static final LatLng SAN_FRAN = new LatLng(37.765927, -122.449972);
// Set position with LatLng only.
mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(SAN_FRAN);
// Set position with LatLng and radius.
mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(SAN_FRAN, 20);
// Set position with LatLng and source.
mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(SAN_FRAN, StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR);
// Set position with LaLng, radius and source.
mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(SAN_FRAN, 20, StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR);
```

Unfortunately, on Xamarin there is no overload of method which accepts StreetViewSource parameter (nor even a class StreetViewSource).
Is there any way to overcome this? Or is this a lack of functionality and this will be added sooner or later (preferably sooner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `IOnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback` implementation you can set the position of your `StreetViewPanorama` to include `StreetViewSource.Outdoor`:

```
public void OnStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama)
{
    panorama.SetPosition(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689), StreetViewSource.Outdoor);
    ~~~
}
```

#### Update:

You need to install at least `70.1501.0-preview...`

```
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="70.1501.0-preview2" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you have read and understood my whole question, but in Xamarin.Android I cannot use this overload of the SetPosition method because it doesn't exist as well as StreetViewSource class.

Comment: Yes, got it thanks. Any clue about Xamarin.iOS though? I'm using the newest version of Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps which is version 2.5.0.1